# How to list objects for specific bucket?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm using cURL and I need to list all files/objects for specific bucket. Here is cURL I use:

```
curl -k "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/myuniquebucket/objects" -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer myAuthString" --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

but it returns this:

```
{    
   "items" : [ ]
}
```

and I have 5-6 files in bucket, for sure.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your bucket is created with "transient", if so, all the items will be automatically removed after 24 hours. If you want to keep these files, please use "persistent" while creating the bucket. More details at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.